# Multiple "operations" in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

So, I have this workflow, where I first join/merge two XML files and then drop out extra elements.
The first part I do with a template with the following contents:

```
   <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//Root/Group" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('part2.xml')//Root/Group" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

This works well enough. Next I run another xslt that removes unnecessary data:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Use" />
```

Which removes elements called "Use" from the resulting document of the first operation. I sure that these two operations can be combined into one single operation, but I just can't figure out how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

(Using XMLSply, so solutionsupto xslt 3.0 are possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see examples of the input documents. I believe you could do:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Group" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('part2.xml')/Root/Group" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Use"/>
```

This is assuming both documents have a root element named `Root` and that `Group` is a child of `Root`.

--
P.S. In XSLT 3.0 the *identity transform* template can be replaced by:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank youvery much. I was apparently very close (but of so far away!) to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `apply-templates` everywhere:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Root/Group" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('part2.xml')//Root/Group" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But we really would need to see more context to tell whether that suffices to interoperate with the other code.

The other options, as you mention XSLT 3, would be to literally execute the second stylesheet from within the first, using the XPath 3.1 `transform` function.